# Drag & Drop Netbeans buttons hidden?

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, drag-and-drop

After dragging and dropping a button in the design view, do I need to set the button to be visible in the source code?  After testing it, the buttons do not appear.

Comment: probably it's hiding, you should use a `LayoutManager` and right click  add From Palette, and select the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

befor using Drag and drop in netbeans you have to Drop `Panel` in form,then drop other component in the `panel`. for example , you want use `commandButton`. first you should Drag and drop `panel` in form then drop `commandbutton` in that panel.
very easily...